# Prevent adjacent component height from increasing within a grid

Tags: html, css

I have 5 components that needs to be in following structure for desktop view.

[image]

The issue I am facing is that when the content grows in one block, example in item1 or item2, it affects other blocks.

So for example if the item2's content is longer which increases its height, that affects item 1 too as follows. (And vice versa, item1 affects item2)

[image]

It seems like .item2 class has no effect. I can comment it out and same effect.

But whether I remove it or try passing in span 0 doesn't make a difference.

How can I fix this, so that item2 can grow as much as it wants to but not affect item block (and vice versa, item1 can grow without affect item2 block)?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box item1">item1</div>
  <div class="box item2">item2</div>
  <div class="box item3">item2</div>
  <div class="box item4">item3</div>
  <div class="box item5">item4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

  .item1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
  .item2 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2 ;
    grid-row: 2 ;
  }
  .item4 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2 ;
    grid-row: 3 ;
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2 ;
    grid-row: 4 ;
  }
```

Comment: I would use flex here instead of grid. With flex you have independent items.

Comment: @Azu Was trying with Flex before but wasn't able to achieve this structure thus went with grid. Could I get an example pls.

Comment: Basically, **you can't** with CSS-Grid. Otherwise it wouldn't be a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve this, if move out of grid flow with `position: absolute;`

```css
.item2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  position: absolute;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box item1">item1</div>
  <div class="box item2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita nesciunt officia, quidem atque vero accusamus quo doloribus, sapiente quas exercitationem culpa dolor saepe adipisci id necessitatibus, blanditiis iusto sint nisi.
  </div>
  <div class="box item3">item2</div>
  <div class="box item4">item3</div>
  <div class="box item5">item4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.wrapper .box {
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid grey; 
}

.wrapper .box.item2{
    float: right;   
}
.wrapper .box.item3,
.wrapper .box.item4,
.wrapper .box.item5{
    clear: left 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box item1">item1</div>
  <div class="box item2">sample text sample text sample text<br>sample text</div>
  <div class="box item3">item3</div>
  <div class="box item4">item4</div>
  <div class="box item5">item5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but was looking to achieve this in grid or flex. float is not encouraged in the codebase unfortunately.